# Need to fire same ruleflow-group multiple times from Single Flow

Tags: drools, jbpm

For reusable perspective, I have one Rule with Rule Flow group. I have use same rule flow group multiple times in flow. Now the situation is its should be fire same rule more then one time,but its only fire that rule single time.

I don't understand why its happens.

Can you give me an idea why its happening and whats the solution for same?

Comment: Very likely the rule doesn't fire again because it already has fired.

Comment: You mean to say there is not way to execute same ruleflow group more then one time. can;'t we reactivate that ruleflow group with the use of session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Rule Task in a flow does not "execute" the rules in a rule-flow-group, it merely activates that group in the agenda so IF there are active rules, they will fire.

If between 2 executions of your Rule Task you modify the session in a way that new activations are created, consecutive executions of your task should fire new activations of those rules.

Hope it helps,

Comment: An easy and efficient way to "refresh" as session would be to include a single fact as a simple pattern `Refresh()` in all rules (of that rule flow group) and call modify on that fact via the API to make everything ready for another usage.

Comment: While using modify block in DRL its goes to infinite loop. and we don't have any api for modify. what do you mean by Refresh(), Is it API available in Drools? Can you please explain bit more.

Comment: Code:rule "Rules_Update BVT Indicator Non BVT"
ruleflow-group "gcefasweep_Non BVT "
dialect "java" 
        when
                $ruleVariables :RuleVariables($sweep: sweep)
        then
               // $sweep.setBvtInd( com.citi.cmb.gce.ce.util.CERulesConstants.NO);
                rulesLogger.logDebug(("Within Update BVT" + $sweep.getBvtInd()), "Within Update BVT");  
                modify($ruleVariables){
     getSweep().setBvtInd( com.citi.cmb.gce.ce.util.CERulesConstants.NO);
    }
end